# git: command not found via bash

Tags: git, bash

I'm quite new to bash, so I'm sorry if I'm asking something silly. Long story short, I'm trying to run the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

ACTION="init" # init or push
USERNAME="username"
PASSWORD="password"
HOST="host.com"
PATH="WebSite/app"
DRYRUN="-D" # use -D for dry-run

cd ./htdocs/app/

git checkout master # switch to master
git push # push to origin
git ftp $ACTION --user $USERNAME --passwd $PASSWORD $DRYRUN ftp://$HOST/$PATH
```

but when I do, I get the following error:

```
deploy.sh: line 12: git: command not found
deploy.sh: line 13: git: command not found
deploy.sh: line 14: git: command not found
```

If I were to follow the steps in the script directly myself, it works as intended, but not when running via bash.

I think it might have something to do with git not being in my $PATH, which looks like this: `/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin:/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin:/home/daniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin:/home/daniel/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/daniel/.rvm/bin` but if that is the case, then I'm not sure how to add it.

Can someone help? Thank you :)

Comment: I'm facing same issue while building CI Bamboo client. This saying **log: command not found** for following command **gitlog=git log ${bamboo.planRepository.previousRevision}..${bamboo.planRepository.revision}** Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've overwritten your PATH in your script.  Don't overwrite it, just append "WebSite/app" to your PATH:

`PATH=$PATH:"WebSite/app"`

Comment: Whoops, so I have. I've changed both references to PATH in my script to REMOTEPATH, and it's now working as intended. Thank you.

Comment: wow... thanks stranger

Answer (score 0):

`PATH=$PATH:"WebSite/app"`
this should help

Answer (score 0):

1. find out where the git executable is so: `which git`
2. if `which` returns ERROR ($? = 1), then `git` is not in your PATH
3. find out where you installed it.
4. replace git in your script with `path_to_git/git`, or modify PATH